# Flask Cognito JWT | Public key not found in jwks.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-cognito

I'm having issues using Flask-Cognito getting the following error:

```
{ "description": "Public key not found in jwks.json", "error": "Invalid Cognito Authentication Token" }
```

I'm using a user pool that I've checked using lambdas and other cookies authentication frameworks..

my Flask Code is basically the github example:

```
# configuration
from flask import Flask
from flask_cognito import cognito_auth_required, current_user, current_cognito_jwt
from flask import jsonify
from flask_cognito import CognitoAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
# initialize extension
# cogauth = CognitoAuth(app)
app.config.update({
    'COGNITO_REGION': 'eu-xxxx',
    'COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID': 'eu-xxxx_xxxx',

    # optional
    'COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID': 'xxxxx',  # client ID you wish to verify user is authenticated against
    'COGNITO_CHECK_TOKEN_EXPIRATION': False,  # disable token expiration checking for testing purposes
    'COGNITO_JWT_HEADER_NAME': 'Authorization',
    'COGNITO_JWT_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
})
CognitoAuth(app)

@app.route('/api/private')
@cognito_auth_required
def api_private():
    # user must have valid cognito access or ID token in header
    # (accessToken is recommended - not as much personal information contained inside as with idToken)
    return jsonify({
        'cognito_username': current_cognito_jwt['username'],  # from cognito pool
        'user_id': current_user.id,  # from your database
    })
```

I'm calling the API like:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/private' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX'
```

Please Help, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is raised if the [public information from the `JWKS_URI` is not downloaded](https://github.com/cgauge/Flask-AWSCognito/blob/v1.3.1/flask_awscognito/services/token_service.py#L58).

This could be a result of the [JWKS_URI being constructed wrong](https://github.com/cgauge/Flask-AWSCognito/blob/v1.3.1/flask_awscognito/services/token_service.py#L34).

For flask_awscognito integration you should set [these properties](https://github.com/cgauge/Flask-AWSCognito/blob/v1.3.1/flask_awscognito/constants.py#L6-L11):

1. `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
2. `AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN`
3. `AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID`
4. `AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID`
5. `AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET`
6. `AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL`

```py
app.config.update({
    'AWS_COGNITO_REGION': 'eu-xxxx',
    'AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID': 'eu-xxxx_xxxx',

    # optional
    'AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID': 'xxxxx',  # client ID you wish to verify user is authenticated against
    'COGNITO_CHECK_TOKEN_EXPIRATION': False,  # disable token expiration checking for testing purposes
    'COGNITO_JWT_HEADER_NAME': 'Authorization',
    'COGNITO_JWT_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
})
```

Comment: Thanks! adding the AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL to the app config did the trick :)